# Mostrar numeros con SYS en una misma linea

Tags: python

```
while True:
    if P1 < 1000:
        P1 + 1
        RL()
        sys.stdout.write(P1) # <-Error aqui ¿?
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)
    else:
        break
```

Intento usar este codigo para intentar mostrar el numero en esa misma linea pero me muestra que solo se puede hacer con strings y no con Enteros, ¿Conocen alguna alternativa? Soy principiante y no se muy bien como buscar estos temas llevo otros 30 minutos buscando.

Comment: La función  `str(x)` transforma `x` en un string. Se usa así `sys.stdout.write(str(P1))`

Answer (score 2):

el problema esta en que `write()` recibe String y no int, para ello agregue `str(P1)` y el error estara corregido:

```
while True:
    if P1 < 1000:
        P1 += 1
        RL()
        sys.stdout.write(str(P1))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)
    else:
        break
```

Ademas de que hay un error en `P1+1` pues solo esta realizando la operacion, mas no la esta guardando. Lo correcto seria: `P1+=1`.